# Relay Isolation

Tags: microcontroller, relay

I have read on many websites to use a separate power supply for relay only. But I've few questions. Can I use some component instead of using a separate power supply ? Or what would really the problem if I use same power supply as microcontroller other than rebooting the microcontroller ?

Relay is 5V and needs to turn off and on an AC ceiling fan motor. And I'm using a relay module which has an optocoupler to switch the NPN transistor attached to input signal pin of relay.

Comment: "other than rebooting the microcontroller" isn't that reason enough?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible to use the same power supply, but it's more difficult - it's mostly an EMC issue- powering the coil itself from the same supply is not a difficult problem if you have an adequate supply, a flyback diode and control the dv/dt. Using a separate supply with opto-isolation helps provide better isolation between the hundreds of volts and several amperes sparking at the contacts and the micro, which might only be able to tolerate a few hundred mV of noise without being disrupted.

That said, there is no hard and fast rule- it may not be necessary and it may not be sufficient. It can depend on circuit design, shielding, grounding, I/O signal conditioning, snubbing, power supply design, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A separate power supply is definitely the ideal way to go, with opto-isolators separating the microprocessor from the relay, but that really isn't necessary for most small relays.

What you do need to do though is put a reverse biased diode across the relay coil to suppress transients on opening, and I always put a snubber circuit across the coil as well; either a self contained one, or a 10 Ohm resistor in series with a .22uF capacitor (for a 5VDC coil); again, for transient suppression.

Relays are quite an inductive load, so you need to protect your control electronics.  Even when using the same supply, I would still stick either a driver transistor or even better an opto-isolator between the uP and the relay coil.